# change background toggle button

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, togglebutton

I try to change the background of a toggle button everytime when it is checked or not,using 2 pictures. At runtime, the toggle button is simple and I don't see any image. This is my code:

```
<Canvas Height="25" Name="canvas1" Width="186" Background="White">
    <ToggleButton Name="toggle1" Height="25" Padding="0" Width="27" Canvas.Left="131" Canvas.Top="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}">

        <ToggleButton.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="OnOffToggleImageStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WpfApp;component/Images/image1.png" Stretch="Uniform" TileMode="None" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WpfApp;component/Images/image2.png" Stretch="Uniform" TileMode="None" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Why does the resource has a key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple things we can point here.

- Firstly you're specifying the `Style` in `ToggleButton.Resources` with a `x:Key`. Thus it's not implicitly set. Setting a `Style` in resources of the item for which it applies in it's own scope is kinda weird. Rather just apply the `Style` directly as `<ToggleButton.Style>`.
- Next, when working with `Style.Triggers`, make it a practice to specify a default Setter. This will prevent some headache for you. Also now instead of having two triggers for IsChecked=False/True, you only need one trigger as the other `Background` can be set as default.
- Finally it seems like all you need from the `ToggleButton` is the `IsChecked` property and switch an `Image`. So just override the `Template` and provide a simple one yourself. This way you assure the behavior to stay consistent in all version of the OS and not rely on internal default template's working nicely for your customization(which wouldn't work in Windows-8 btw, what you're trying here for `IsChecked=True` due to internal overrides in default `ControlTemplate`)

So putting this all together we get:

```
<Style x:Key="MyToggleButtonStyle"
        TargetType="ToggleButton">
  <Setter Property="Background">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WpfApp;component/Images/image2.png"
                  Stretch="Uniform"
                  TileMode="None" />
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Border Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
              Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WpfApp;component/Images/image1.png"
                      Stretch="Uniform"
                      TileMode="None" />
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

and apply it to your `ToggleButton`

```
<ToggleButton Name="toggle1" Height="25" Padding="0" Width="27" Canvas.Left="131" Canvas.Top="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}" Style="{DynamicResource MyToggleButtonStyle}">
```

you can ofc remove the Key in the Style and make it implicitly apply to "all" `ToggleButton`'s within the scope of the Style definition if you choose to.

Answer (score 3):

Can you check if the build action for your images is Embedded Resource please?

Comment: they are not in embedded resource.

Comment: Can you change the build action to Embedded Resource for those images in your project and try again. WPF needs the images to be embedded resources for it to use them in runtime

Comment: It's the same, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 2):

Define the style directly for your togglebutton like below. it should fix your issue:

```
<ToggleButton>
      <ToggleButton.Style>
            <Style  TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WpfApp;component/Images/image2.png" Stretch="Uniform" TileMode="None" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WpfApp;component/Images/image1.png" Stretch="Uniform" TileMode="None" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the x:Key and it will work.